# Shows image on browser after resizing in Lambda with API Gateway

Tags: python, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am trying to create a lambda function which resizes images from s3 and response it via API Gateway.

The request goes to the API Gateway endpoint and it triggers the lambda function. The lambda function resizes it and tries to give the response it as binary but it can't do it.

I have developed the lambda function with Python.

This is the Integration Response configurations in my API Gateway.
[image]

This is the Method Response configurations.
[image]

This is the Binary Support configurations.
[image]

There isn't any problem in resizing code because it can resize the image on s3 and upload it successfully into the resize s3 bucket.
But when I try to response it as binary, the API Gateway can not response it and I don't know why.

This is the response code in Lambda.

```
upload_path = /tmp/resized-test.jpg
with open(upload_path, 'rb') as f:
        image_content = f.read()

    encoded_string = str(binascii.hexlify(image_content))

    return {
        'header': {
            'Content-Type': content_type
        },
        'body': encoded_string
    }
```

Comment: in response can u send URL of resized image ? That would be much more simpler to implement...

Comment: @Deepak do you mean that I response the s3 resized URL and redirect it by 301 in API Gateway?

Comment: yes ; or on client side once u receive the resized URL u can redirect on client side or open a new tab with the returned URL.. doing on client end will be much more simpler

Comment: @Deepak actually, this 301 seems better but I am not sure how a browser acts when the URL is redirected.